# scp file to different user in the remote server from local

Tags: linux, scp, su

generally, i login to a server xyz.com using my login credentials(myuserid@xyz.com), 
my home = /home/user/myuserid/

after login, i do "su - someuser" to access the files.

i would like to copy a file from local machine to a directory in someuser eg: /abc/someuser/temp

for this, i am using 
scp somefile.txt myuserid@xyz.com:/abc/someuser/temp/

it is asking my password for myuserid and then says.. /abc/someuser/temp/ permission denied

what command shall i use to copy a file to su in remote host?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to use someuser's credentials to do the scp

```
scp somefile.txt someuser@xyz.com:/abc/someuser/temp/
```

Alternatively you can give `myuserid` permission to `someuser`'s home directory.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, scp somefile.txt someuser@xyz.com:/abc/someuser/temp/ it wont allow to directly connect to the host using someuser credentials.

Comment: Then you'll have to give yourself permissions to someuser's home directory